# Extract file data when receiving ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android

I can receive fileinfo in ACTION_VIEW like this:

```
String[] dataFileds = new String[]{
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            OpenableColumns.SIZE};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, dataFileds, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    fileLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
    title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
    size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));

    cursor.close();
```

It has an URI that could look like this: **content://downloads/all_downloads/387**

My problem is when receiving a file through ACTION_SEND. Here I get an URI that look like this: **file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Arkitekturvalg.pdf**

When I use the same code to get the file data, I get an null pointer error on `cursor`.

How will I be able to receive the file information when a user want to share a file to my app?

*Note that bothe of the URIs is for the same file.*

Comment: You have the path to the file on the file system. What kind of information do you want? You have already the 'display name` (Arkitekturvalg.pdf). And file size you can retrieve with the File class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, then use `getLastPathSegment()` to get the "display name" (filename). Then, use `new File(uri.getPath()).length()` to get the length of the file.